# What are the security risks of using mysql and php with UTF-8? Is it worth it if not going mulilingual soon?

Tags: php, security, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have read about a couple of risks of using UTF-8 and there are probably more. What are the security issues, are they difficult to address and do the risks outweigh the benefits of using unicode?

http://www.erich-kachel.de/?p=806 It is known, that interpreting non-shortest form UTF-8 is a security issue.

http://secunia.com/advisories/41724/ The security issue is caused due to the "utf8_decode()" function incorrectly decoding certain UTF-8 sequences. This can be exploited to e.g. bypass security filters and subsequently conduct cross-site scripting and SQL injection attacks.

I would consider myself an advanced beginner programmer and I am the only person coding where I work. Having a multilingual website where I work is not currently a requirement, but in the future it could be.

Comment: there are functions to avoid most attacks (addslashes,mysql_real_escape_string) just remember to sanitize all user inputs and only allow chars you know are safe ([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]) ect, there are also many user input sanitizer functions like the one here http://www.erich-kachel.de/?p=638 XSS & sql injections is not a new problem...

Comment: So until I add an input sanitizer to be safe I should limit myself to the characters listed in the brackets. I assume limiting a site to ([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]) should be done regardless of the encoding I choose and adding unicode with an input sanitizer will allow me to use a variety of alphabets with reasonable safety.

Answer (score 5):

George,

The vulnerability you mention is actually about three years old.  While it's true that Unicode support in PHP isn't complete, you can use UTF8 safely so long as you take standard precautions with regards to customer data (IE, never, ever trusting it) and handle your data reasonably carefully.  I don't think at this point UTF8 is any more worrisome than any other input.

Make certain that you aren't using a legacy version of PHP and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is easier to find bad news from 2 years ago than something saying it works today.

Comment: It's no problem, and yeah - you're right.  The internet isn't a relational datastore!  That doesn't mean it isn't a great idea to keep reading security advisories, but for the most part with a little care you can protect yourself.

Comment: If I've helped you, please consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer by clicking on the arrow or checkmark next to my post.